# Using one of the service methods declared as module pattern in another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular service like this:

```
videoApp.factory('cacheLoader', function ($http, $filter, $rootScope) {
    this.self = this;
    return {
        load: function (url, allowCache) {
            if(allowCache == false || localStorage.getItem(url) && (parseInt(localStorage.getItem(url + 'time')) + 20000) < (new Date().getTime()) || (!localStorage.getItem(url) )) {
                $http.get(url).success(function (data) {

                    $rootScope.allData = data;
                    $rootScope.videos = data;

                    $rootScope.categories = $filter('categoryFilter')(data);

                    if(allowCache == true && parseInt(localStorage.getItem(url + 'time')) + 20000 < (new Date().getTime() )) {
                        localStorage.setItem(url, JSON.stringify(data));
                        localStorage.setItem(url + 'time', new Date().getTime());
                    }

                });
            } else {
                $rootScope.allData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url));
                $rootScope.videos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url));
                $rootScope.categories = $filter('categoryFilter')(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url)));
            }
        },
        getFilteredResults: function (category, data, callback) {
            callback = callback || $filter('articleFilter');
            $rootScope.videos = callback(category, data);
            return $rootScope.videos;
        }
    };
});
```

Now, what I want to use cacheLoader.getFilteredResults  inside cacheLoader.load function. this is a window object, so I can't point on it, I tried to bind this to the whole module pattern, but it throw error.

Is there any way how to accomplish what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `this.getFilteredResults` inside the `load` method:

```
videoApp.factory('cacheLoader', function ($http, $filter, $rootScope) {
    this.self = this;
    return {
        load: function () {
            this.getFilteredResults();
        },
        getFilteredResults: function () {
            alert('hi');
        }
    };
});
```

And if you need to handle referring to `this` inside a callback, then do something like:

```
return {
    load: function () {
        var that = this;
        doSomeThing().then(function(data) {
            that.getFilteredResults();
        });
    },
    getFilteredResults: function () {
        alert('hi');
    }
};
```